# How to add Authorization token in ReactFormBuilder ( react-form-builder2 )

Tags: reactjs, formbuilder

Im using "react-form-builder2" npm to save dynamic forms, Backend API needs authorization token for all requests. How to add Authorization token in ReactFormBuilder ( react-form-builder2 ).

Comment: Add the token to the header of your webservice request.

Comment: there is no way to add header in react-form-builder2 @C.Helling

Comment: You can't intercept the request via the `onSubmit` prop and add headers and submit from there?